# Spring MVC 3 — Bind properties of object list within model element

Tags: data-binding, spring-mvc

I have a JSP generated form that needs to present the user with a list of options. Some of these are single-instance options (such as whether or not to generate a table of contents), and that's working fine. I now need to add a list of subordinate options and allow the user to turn each one on or off. I can generate the list of options in the JSP page, and give each one a unique ID. I hope to represent one with a `<form:checkbox/>` element in the form.

The option class looks like this:

```
// Option class
public class PdfCatalogOptions
{
    private boolean isTableOfContentsIncluded;
    private List<ProductGroup> productGroups;

    public boolean getTableOfContentsIncluded () {
        return isTableOfContentsIncluded;
    }    

    public PdfCatalogOptions setTableOfContentsIncluded ( final boolean isTableOfContentsIncluded ) {
        this.isTableOfContentsIncluded = isTableOfContentsIncluded;
        return this;
    }

    public List<ProductGroup> getProductGroups() {
        return productGroups;
    }

    public PdfCatalogOptions setProductGroups( final List<ProductGroup> setProductGroups ) {
        this.productGroups = productGroups;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The product group class looks like this:

```
public class ProductGroup
{
    private String  groupName;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public String getGroupName () {
        return groupName;
    }

    public ProductGroup setGroupName ( final String groupName ) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        return this;
    }

    public Boolean getIsSelected () {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public ProductGroup setIsSelected ( final boolean selected ) {
        isSelected = selected;
        return this;
    }
}
```

In the `get` handler within the controller, I do this:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String get ( final Model model ) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute ( "options", new PdfCatalogOptions ().setProductGroups ( buildProductGroupList () ) );
    return FormName.GENERATE_CATALOG;
}
```

The logic within `buildProductGroupList` is of no consequence — it just generates an `ArrayList` of `ProductGroup` objects populated with the data I need.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to convince Spring to bind to the fields within the individual `ProductGroup` objects inside the `PdfCatalogOptions` object.

The JSP looks like this:

```
<form:form action="generateCatalog.do" commandName="options">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><form:errors cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="catalog.include.toc"/></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="tableOfContentsIncluded"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="options.productGroups" var="productGroup">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><form:checkbox path="productGroup.isSelected"/>blah</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

In the inner `<c:forEach...>` loop I cannot find the right incantation to get Spring to bind to the individual `ProductGroup` objects so I can end up with a list of `ProductGroup` objects with the `isSelected` properties set as required by the user.

As presented, it's complaining that:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'productGroup' of bean class [<redacted>.PdfCatalogOptions]: Bean property 'productGroup' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

---

**EDIT 1**: This correctly lists all product groups:

```
<c:forEach items="${options.productGroups}" var="pg">
    <tr>
        <td>${pg.groupName}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The values are there and display as I would expect. What I can't do, however, is find a way to bind the value path to the checkbox. If I add `<form:checkbox path="pg.isSelected"/>` then I'm told that `pg` is not a property of `PdfCatalogOptions`.

If I add `<form:checkbox path="${pg.isSelected}"/>` then I'm told — somewhat predictably — that `true` is not a property of `PdfCatalogOptions`.

Comment: The error is expected. There is no productGroup field in PdfCatalogOptions. It is productGroups

Comment: The `productGroup` is the `c:forEach<...>` loop variable.

Comment: Check the generated html. If the input (of type checkbox) has name that contains "productGroup" instead of "productGroups", then obviously this error will occur.

Comment: @Andrew: Did you get the solution of this problem?? I'm facing the same problem.